# Hosting multiple domain names with one ip: DNS/apache2 issue

Tags: apache-2.2, domain-name-system

I am trying to do something fairly simple. We have one dedicated server at ip `[our server ip]`

We have purchased several domain names.

I would like to host the sites under one ip.

I set up the zone file using the interface the company provides. Here is how it looks:

[image]

In apache2, running on Ubuntu 10.04, I go to /etc/apache2/sites-available/ and create a file named `[domain name].com`

The contents of this file are:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName [domain name].com
    DocumentRoot /var/www
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I run the command `sudo a2ensite [domain name].com` and restart the server. It doesn't work.

I changed the DNS records some 28 hours ago. What could be the issue?

What is working is the 'normal' site. I checked the DNS file and all the `IN A` types are pointing to the server ip.

What is different are the name servers; the working site has name servers from the site we bought the domains. The other one has name servers from a different place.

What could be wrong here?

Thanks,
Dane

Comment: Many possible things -- start with the basics: does opening `http://ext.ern.al.ip` in your browser get through the firewall to the web server (if not it is more-likely a firewall issue); is your internal DNS hosting the same zone as the external DNS (if so, did you update the internal DNS as well?); did you clear your DNS lookup cache from your client *and* your local DNS server; is the TTL for your domain longer than 28 hours?

Comment: Have you definitely turned on name based virtual hosting? You'll need to set the `NameVirtualHost` directive to: `NameVirtualHost *:80`

Comment: @JamesYale yes, I have it set once in ports.conf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, if you are unsure that the DNS records have been updated try to `ping www.yourdomain.com` and see if the packets are being sent to the correct server IP address.

Then check that Apache is listening `netstat -l -n | grep ":80"` and that your firewall has port 80 open `iptables -L -n | grep "dpt:80"`.

The contents of /var/www is normally used/reserved for the default site in `apache2/sites-available/`.  When running virtual sites on a box I create a different directory for each `/var/www/site1 /var/www/site2 etc...` and set them as the DocumentRoot which is matched by the unique ServerName (domain name) in each config file under `sites-available`.  This will prevent any confusion for Apache and also secure each site from other users (if providing FTP access per site).

Answer (score 2):

your document root `DocumentRoot /var/www` should have seperate directories for each of the domains.
Heres an example of how I do my domain and sub domain

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
                ServerName www.mydomain.com
                ServerAlias mydomain.com
                ServerAdmin tech@mydomain.com
                DocumentRoot "/var/www/mydomain.com"
                <Directory /var/www/mydomain.com/admin>
                                AllowOverride All
                                Allow from all
                </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
                ServerName www.dev.mydomain.com
                ServerAlias dev.mydomain.com
                ServerAdmin tech@mydomain.com
                DocumentRoot "/var/www/dev.mydomain.com"
                <Directory /var/www/dev.mydomain.com>
                                AllowOverride All
                                Allow from all
                </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```